# Magento site generation error - products not added to sitemap

Tags: magento, cron, sitemap

I have this weird issue where products are not being added to the sitemap.
We run a multi-store with 12 stores, so also 12 sitemaps.

Sitemaps setup correctly and cron working properly.

All sitemaps are working correctly except the last 2 sitemaps.
In the last two stores the products aren't added to the sitemap.
The categories and cms pages are all added, but no products.

When I use the generate sitemap button in catalog/google sitemap, the sitemaps are correct again. But as you can imagine, I want the sitemaps to be correctly generated by the cron.

I've enabled reporting. And found the following error in sitemap_generate.log:

```
[23-Sep-2016 21:10:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 53: parser error : Comment not terminated 
<!--
    <reference name="header">
        <ac in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
[23-Sep-2016 21:10:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():         <!-- This block is inside of the header block on mage EE, so it could in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

[23-Sep-2016 21:10:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():           ^ in /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

I don't know what it means and that it is relevant to the problem.
I run magento 1.9.1.0 with all the latest security updates.

So what could be wrong? Please note, that the sitemap.xml files are generated correctly and cron is setup correctly etc. Cron.php runs every 5 minutes.

If you need any more information please ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I posted the question on Magento stack exchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143088/magento-site-generation-error-products-not-added-to-sitemap